# JSONAPISerializer not returning underscore case to API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am trying to retrieve a single record by returning

```
singleGroup: this.store.findRecord('individual_group', group_id)
```

I am then getting this error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/individual-groups/349 404 (Not Found)
```

where it seems to be dasherizing `individual_groups` to `individual-groups`

Now in the API documentation, an individual group is found by doing a GET request to `api/v1/individual_groups/:id`

I'm using the `JSONAPIAdapter` and already have a serializer set up as so:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
        return Ember.String.underscore(attr);
    },
    keyForRelationship: function(attr) {
        return Ember.String.underscore(attr);
    }
});
```

but it does not seem to be affecting this particular case.

Is there a way to make sure that when I call `this.store.findRecord('individual_group', group_id)` it will make the request to the API using

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/individual_groups/349
```

instead of

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/individual-groups/349
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redefine `pathForType` [adapter method](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization). The  [default implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.0.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/json-api-adapter.js#L104) uses dasherize:

```
  //as is
  pathForType: function(modelName) {
    var dasherized = Ember.String.dasherize(modelName);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(dasherized);
  }

  //to be
  pathForType: function(modelName) {
    var underscored = Ember.String.underscore(modelName);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(underscored);
  }
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks!